# Why is this virtual constexpr function not recognised as constant?

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-c++, c++20

I have the following example code using `virtual constexpr` from C++20 which does not compile:

```cpp
enum legCount {
    APODA = 0,
    BIPEDAL = 2,
    QUADRUPEDAL = 4,
};

class Animal {
public:
    constexpr virtual legCount getLegCount() = 0;
};

class Tiger : public Animal {
public:
    constexpr legCount getLegCount() { return QUADRUPEDAL; }

    void manipulateLegsArray() {
        unsigned char arr[getLegCount()];
    }
};
```

This code compiles with Clang however MSVC complains that `getLegCount` in `unsigned char arr[getLegCount()];` does not evaluate to a constant expression (failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime). Is MSVC correct here and if so why is this?

Further, how can I mimic this functionality in a conformant way? I would like to have an abstract base class where all derived classes must implement the function and the function must be a constexpr.

Exact compiler error message as follow:

```
D:\Projects\temp\demo\main.cpp(17,32): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [D:\Projects\temp\out\demo\demo.vcxproj]
D:\Projects\temp\demo\main.cpp(17,21): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [D:\Projects\temp\out\demo\demo.vcxproj]
D:\Projects\temp\demo\main.cpp(17,21): message : see usage of 'this' [D:\Projects\temp\out\demo\demo.vcxproj]
```

Comment: please include the compiler error message in the question

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai edited question to included error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`manipulateLegsArray` function can be called at runtime by another class that inherits from your class, so `getLegCount()` must be resolved at runtime, your array now becomes a variable length array, which MSVC doesn't support, it is only supported by clang/gcc.

you could enforce the derived class to implement something that is constexpr using CRTP.

```
enum legCount {
    APODA = 0,
    BIPEDAL = 2,
    QUADRUPEDAL = 4,
};

template< typename T>
class Animal {
public:
    static constexpr legCount getLegCount()
    {
        return T::legCount_v;
    }
};

class Tiger : public Animal<Tiger> {
public:
    constexpr static legCount legCount_v = QUADRUPEDAL;

    void manipulateLegsArray() {
        unsigned char arr[getLegCount()];
    }
};
```

Comment: Note, you can give GCC and Clang the option `-Werror=vla` to disable VLAs.

Comment: ... or `-pedantic-errors`

Comment: thanks, that answers my question on _why_ but in regards to my second question do you know of any way I can replicate the intended functionality for MSVC?

Comment: @user_5309734  Using a dynamic datastructure like a vector, for example.

Comment: @user_5309734 you can use CRTP as i have shown in the edit, but you should be using `vector` if you wanted someone to inherit `Tiger` and override `getLegCount`.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I settled on a very similar templating solution. Any derived class of 'Tiger' should not modify 'getLegCount' so this is an adequate solution. Thank you.